# Can managed packages have hidden validation rules? Keep getting Field Custom Validation Error

Tags: apex, soql, managed-package, validation, failing-tests

I am trying to fix some test coverage. I have about a dozen fails across this org and every test fails for the same reason. The error is:

`FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, &lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:normal;&quot;&gt; Price Book name entered is invalid. Please use the &lt;b&gt;Choose Price Book&lt;/b&gt; button to change the Price Book.&lt;/span&gt;: []`

I'm not quite sure where I should look. I used the Tooling API to query all validation rules to see if any of them throw their error and that didn't show me anything.

Kugamon is installed and the object that is created which triggers this error is one of their objects.

Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

Apex can also run validations which cause `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`, so this erro may well be caused by code. You should contact the package author for support.